# Should this bolt be tightened?

Tags: derailleur-rear, shifting, mechanical

This bolt on the left side makes the derailleur move hardly or loosely on the derailleur hanger. I don't know how it should be set. Should I keep it tight or loose?

[image: deore rear derailleur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the B-axle. It should be tightened to 8-10 Nm using a 5 mm hex key. Here is an excerpt from the dealer's manual to illustrate this:

[image]

Comment: How tight is 8-10 nm? I don't have a torque key. Actually the bolt can move only 90 degrees.

Comment: 8-10 Nm is definitely not loose. Just make sure it is tight without putting too much force. The torque there is not as critical as with carbon parts, so even if you are a bit off, it is okay. If you unscrew it and inspect the threads, is everything looking good?

Comment: I didn't unscrew it. Thx.

Comment: My experience with Shimano Shadow and Shadow+  derailleurs that utilize this B-axke bracket for conventional mounting, is that freeness of rotation at that point is quite varied between different derailleurs. In other words, 10Nm torque on that bolt on a Deore derailleur and the bracket swivels freely as if the bolt is too loose. The same torque on the same bolt on an XT derailleur and that bracket will be held pretty fast.  What does matter is that the bracket tab on the inside is resting fully on the bike's hanger B-tab (the tail at the bottom of the derailleur hanger).

Comment: @Ender 10nm is like putting 10kg on the end of a 10cm hex key, literally, by definition. So if you have a 10cm allen key, you should feel the same force on your finger as if you were lifting a 10kg weight with that finger.